# tso function in tsoutliers fails with message about xreg, colnames

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I'm using `tsoutliers` v0.6.5 in R v3.2.3 and I'm encountering an issue with the tso function. Also, using `forecast` v7.3 and KFKSDS v1.6 if that's helpful.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tsoutliers)

s <- ts(
  c(61,26,10,2,6,20,139,185,132,162,160,140,148,
   173,171,160,119,81,18,5,2,25,141,181,130,175,
   160,143,144,168,154,161,109,66,23,5,4,35,122,
   161,129,168,139,145,176,176,177,156,89,62,24,
   6,1,2,24,134,208,187,215,211,239,322)
)

tso(s)
```

For me this produced the following error message:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (ncol(xreg) == 1) nmxreg else paste(nmxreg,  :
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a bug in `tsoutliers`?

Comment: As an update, upgrading to R 3.4.0 and reinstalling tsoutliers changed the error message slightly:
`Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`

Comment: Not sure what the error is about, but FYI your series has clear periodicity, but since it has the default frequency of 1 (you did not specify one in the call to `ts`), `tso` will use `auto.arima` (by default) without any seasonal ARIMA models, and you are unlikely to find a good model at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. When all the potential outliers were discarded in the second step of the procedure, the matrix of outliers xreg gets no columns and this gave error when setting column names by `auto.arima`. In order to avoid the error, now `xreg` is set to `NULL` .

The updated version of the package is available on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tsoutliers).

Comment: Hello sir, i just learn your package. it's wonderfull. but i got problem when i run "tso" function, it gives error and said "Error in auto.arima(x = c(2288, 598, 1152, 1457, 978, 498, 5895617, 3046,  :  xreg is rank deficient". Please help sir!!

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba this comment should rather be a new question.

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba Anyway, the error suggests that there may be too many regressors in the model, some of them (or a combinations of them) containing 
similar information, rendering the matrix of regressors rank deficient. This is sometimes the case when the ARIMA model does not capture the overall dynamic of the data and most of it is explained by outliers regressors. I recommend you reduce the number of regressors to be considered, e.g. `types=c("AO", "LS")`, use a lower critical value, e.g. `cval=2.5`, see also argument `discard.method'. Then check the residuals and reassess the model.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the advice, sorry for late response. I have 9 million data, is it possible to use tsoutliers with running time under 30 minutes? Thanks again.

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba I'm afraid not, tsoutliers is fully coded in R and the implementation is not intended for such large data sets or to deal with time constraints.

Comment: Hi sir, i got "Error in attributes(oeff) <- attributes(y) : 
  cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length vector". How do i solve this problem? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba I would recommend you to post your question in a new post containing enough information that reproduces your error.

Comment: ah i see sir.. OK sir i would. Thanks btw